# PHP Query - Check string character

Tags: php, string-matching

```
if (substr('xcazasd123', 0, 2) === 'ax'){
}
```

> Above code is working where it able to check if the "variable" is
> starting with 'ax',  but what if i wanted to check "multiple"
> different validation ?

for example : 'ax','ab','ac' ? Without creating multiple if statement

Comment: $value = substr('xcazasd123', 0, 2);
$compare_array = array('ab','ax','ac');
if(in_array($value,$compare_array)){
  // Run your code
}

Try using in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array to store your keywords and then use `in_array()` if you want to avoid multiple if statements.

```
$key_words =["ax","ab","ac"]
if (in_array( substr('yourstringvalue', 0, 2), $key_words ){
  //your code
}
```

**References:**
[in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

If this sub-string is always in the same place - easy and fast is `switch`

```
// $x = string to pass 
switch(substr($x,0,2)){
    case 'ax':  /* do ax */ break;
    case 'ab':  /* do ab */ break;
    case 'ac':  /* do ac */ break;  // break breaks execution
    case 'zy':  /* do ZY */         // without a break this and next line will be executed
    case 'zz':  /* do ZZ */ break;  // for zz only ZZ will be executed
    default:    /* default proceed */}
```

`switch` pass exact values in `case` - any other situation are not possible or weird and redundant.
`switch` can also evaluate through `default` to another one `switch` or other conditions

[manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: thanks , this was a good way if i have multiple scenerio for different case , already in my note , thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match approach for test the string:

```
if(preg_match('/^(ax|ab|ac)/', '1abcd_test', $matches)) {
    echo "String starts with: " . $matches[1];
} else {
    echo "String is not match";
}
```

Example: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=26b5de58bff00541921475fb021efb1b&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

You can learn about [PHP Regular Expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_regex.asp) fro more complicated string matching